# Is there an equivalent of KDE Activities for GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, kde, gnome3, kde-activities

I've been using GNOME 3 for a while and I miss something like [KDE Activities](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Activities).

A nice explanation about KDE Activities can be found on [this page](https://www.datamation.com/open-source/the-mystery-of-kde-activities-1.html):

> [...] when you take the time to learn about Activities, you'll find them a
>   natural extension of the desktop metaphor that just might help you to
>   work more efficiently.
>
> Activities are a super-set of Virtual Desktops. They don't replace
>   Virtual Desktops -- in fact, each Activity can have its own set of
>   Virtual Desktops if you choose. Instead, Activities are alternative
>   desktops, each of which can have its own wallpaper, icons, and
>   widgets.
>
> The most common way to use Activities is to create one for each
>   general task that you do. For instance, you might set up one Activity
>   with all the apps and widgets that you need for coding or writing.
>   Another desktop might have your web browser, email reader, chat
>   application and other Internet applications. Yet another might be your
>   dumping ground for articles that you want to read later.
>
> Alternatively, you might set up Activities according to location, with
>   different desktops for work, school, and home. [...]

Is there something like that for GNOME 3? I would like to have an standard activity and another activity for studying.

Comment: Almost one year ago and no answer... :(